# Tensorflow Placeholder, TypeError:set_shape() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, tensorflow, typeerror, placeholder

> I am trying to use tensorflow to build my own CNN network, but when I
>   use *Placeholder*, some error happens.

***TypeError: set_shape() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given***

The code is like this:

---

def train():

```
# error happens in this line:
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[BATCH_SIZE,
                               inference.IMAGE_SIZE,
                               inference.IMAGE_SIZE,
                               inference.NUM_INPUT_CHANEL],
                               name='input_x')          

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[BATCH_SIZE,
                                inference.OUTPUT_CHANEL],
                                name='input_y')

regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARAZTION_RATE) 

y = inference.inference(x, True, regularizer)

global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)

variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY, global_step)

variable_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())

cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits( labels=tf.argmax(y_, 1), logits=y)

cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

loss =cross_entropy_mean + tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'))

learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(LEARNING_RATE_BASE, global_step, num_examples/BATCH_SIZE, LEARNING_RATE_DECAY)

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

with tf.control_dependencies([train_step, variable_averages_op]):

    train_op = tf.no_op(name='train')

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for i in range(TRAINING_STEPS):

        dataset= DataConverted.read_datasets()

        xs=dataset.train

        ys=dataset.lables

        reshaped_xs = np.reshape(xs, (BATCH_SIZE, inference.IMAGE_SIZE, inference.IMAGE_SIZE, inference.NUM_INPUT_CHANEL))

        reshaped_ys = np.reshape(ys, (BATCH_SIZE,inference.OUTPUT_NODE))

        _, loss_value, step = sess.run([train_op, loss, global_step], feed_dict={x: reshaped_xs, y_: reshaped_ys})

        if i%100== 0:

            print("After %d training step(s), loss on training batch is %f." % (step, loss_value))

            saver.save(sess, os.path.join(MODEL_SAVE_PATH, MODEL_NAME), global_step=global_step)

def main(argv=None):

      train()

if __name__ == '__main__':

      tf.app.run()
```

The complete error information like this:

---

```
 -  File "E:/WN/MachineLearning/FirstTry/train.py", line 31, in train
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[BATCH_SIZE,inference.IMAGE_SIZE,inference.IMAGE_SIZE,inference.NUM_INPUT_CHANEL],name='input_x')
 - File "C:\Users\JJK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1548, in placeholder
return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
 - File "C:\Users\JJK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 2094, in _placeholder
name=name)
 - File "C:\Users\JJK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
 -File "C:\Users\JJK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2632, in create_op
set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
 - File "C:\Users\JJK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1930, in set_shapes_for_outputs
output.set_shape(s)

- TypeError: set_shape() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

---

> I really don't understand why this error happens and how to avoid it. Can anyone help me?
>   me. Thanks a ton.

Comment: When you call `tf.placeholder`, what are the values of `BATCH_SIZE`, `inference.IMAGE_SIZE`, and `inference.NUM_INPUT_CHANEL`?

Comment: The values of *BATCH_SIZE* is 3, inference. *IMAGE_SIZE* is 175 and *inference.NUM_INPUT_CHANEL* is 1.

Comment: I can't seem to generate the same error.  Can you post your entire file?  I'm particularly interested in the `inference` object and its class.

Comment: I have uploaded the code file to this blog [link](http://blog.csdn.net/liu_nian/article/details/78615128) , hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again, I should add something. I try to run another file that contains the  use of placeholder, I got this problems too.  So strange!

Comment: I needed to comment out `print(loss.shape())` in the `train` file, and the `DataConverted` module seems to be custom code.  Once that's done I get the error `ValueError: Incompatible shapes between op input and calculated input gradient.  Forward operation: layer9_deconv4/conv2d_transpose.  Input index: 2. Original input shape: (1, 40, 40, 32).  Calculated input gradient shape: (1, 43, 43, 32)`, which suggests that the output of layer8 is incompatible with the shape of layer9.  This is an awfully deep NN; you might consider commenting out most of your layers to see if your scaffolding works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have solved the 'placeholder' problem by rebuild the tensorflow environment, this may not be the best way,but it solved. After that I also met the problem you mentioned, but I know how to solve it. I need to work more on my data flow. Thanks again for your help.